# How do I make node express give a response out based on the input for the same url

Tags: node.js, express

I have to have the same endpoint give out different responses based on the input it gets. How do I mock it using express?

This is the sample I have

```
 var express = require('express')

 var app = express() // the main app

 process.env.PORT = 3301

 let users = {
 1: {
    id: '1',
    username: 'Robin Wieruch',
 },
 2: {
    id: '2',
    username: 'Dave Davids',
 },
};
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
   return res.send(Object.values(users));
});
```

Now this always responds with the users list when I call it with localhost:3301. How do I make it take a input response and give out a response based on the input for the same api call (i.e. change response based on the input). The input can be either a json or xml input and output has to change.

example input json:

```
{
  1: {
    id: '1',
    username: 'Robin Wieruch',
  },
  2: {
    id: '2',
    username: 'Dave Davids',
  },
};
```

output response: `123`

input xml:

```
 <XML FileVersion="09/30/2019"><ActionRequest method="select" 
 entityschema="SYSADM" entity="TEST" entitytype="table"><Field 
 Name="USER_ID" Value="" /><wheres><Field field="USER_ID" 
 Value="239023 where <Field field="USER_ID" Value="237915|510356" 
 condition="IN" /></wheres></ActionRequest></XML>
```

OUTPUT XML:

```
API RESPONSE <XML>
  <exceptions />
    <rows />
     <results>
      <PAYABLE_DIST />
      <PAYABLE>
      <DataRow>
         <USER_ID>237915</USER_ID>
         <DATE>2019-3-17</DATE>
      </DataRow>
      <DataRow>
         <USER_ID>237950</USER_ID>
         <DATE>dynamic date field</DATE>
       </DataRow>

    ...
```

Newbie to express. TIA

Comment: Those inputs and outputs look like _completely different data_ so why would your single endpoint service both? Make one for whatever that json request/response is (it's a GET, so it's entirely unclear what it's supposed to do), and a different one for that XML req/res (which looks like you're allowing people to actually send you database query instructions, which is _horrendously_ insecure and really should be an API endpoint that does not reveal your database schema in the slightest, only offering filter parameters for what is in your API endpoint documentation)

Comment: Unfortunately we have a third party end point given to us like this and to test it in my local, I have to simulate the api calls and check the UI actions based on the input values. So what I am trying is to basically mock what the third party api is to see actions in our UI. Their API takes both json and XML for the same api call and spits a response based on the input.

Comment: that's insane, but if you have no recourse then you have no recourse. GET requests don't let you send data, only URL arguments, so step one is to start using `app.post` or `app.put` (depending on what the real API end point uses) and using `body-parser` (explained in the express documentation) or if you're passing data using URL encoded or even base64 strings, you'll have to access `request.query` (again, see the express documentation for more detailed information)